# Discrete measures converging weakly

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ be any sequence of non-negative real numbers with $\sum_i a_i = 1$. Define the discrete measure $\mu$ by $\mu(\cdot) = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} a_i \delta_i(\cdot)$, where $\delta_i(\cdot)$ is a point-mass at the positive integer $i$. Construct a sequence $\{\mu_n\}$ of probability measures, each having a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, such that $\mu_n\Rightarrow \mu$.
>
> *Note:* $\mu_n\Rightarrow \mu$ denotes the weak convergence of $\mu_n$ to $\mu$.

**Official solution:**
[image]

---

My problem is that I always thought that density functions have to be *continuous*, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, or does it? So is the official solution correct?

Or what would be an example of *continuous* density functions $f_n$ for which the measures $\mu_n(A) = \int_A f_n \, d\lambda$ converge weakly to $\mu$? Should I use "Gaussian peaks"?

Comment: 1. Density functions are in general not continuous. 2. Yes, Gaussian peaks are a good idea.